# Android - Media Recorder pause in API versions level lower than 24 ?

Tags: java, android

I found out about the pause method in MediaRecorder.

> Pauses recording. Call this after start(). You may resume recording with resume() without reconfiguration, as opposed to stop(). It does nothing if the recording is already paused. When the recording is paused and resumed, the resulting output would be as if nothing happend during paused period, immediately switching to the resumed scene.

This is neat , but the method is supported in API levels 24 and higher only. Is there any method or solution that can do the same for lower versions ? I require the pause functionality for my Sound Recorder.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that in pre 24. An ugly workaround would be to stop and start a new recording and then append them using [AudioRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord)